# How to access login session data out side of application folder in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In my website, I need to manage CSS for all logged in users.
I need to show different header colours, for example blue for one user and red for another.

Here I've managed everything dynamically, but I'm unable to get the logged in user type from outside of application folder. This is because my dynamic css page is inside the style folder, which is outside the application folder of CI.

I'll show some of my codes, Which can be helpful.

```html
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

    if($type=="admin")
    {
        $settingButtonColor = "#990000";
    }

    if($type=="student")
    {
        $settingButtonColor = "#990001";
    }

    if($type=="teacher")
    {
         $settingButtonColor = "#990002";
    }
?>
```

```css
.sett_btn
{
    background-color:<?php echo $settingButtonColor;?> !important;
}
```

Like this. But how can I get that session type, as this variable is accessible inside the applications folder.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: If you want to add PHP in your CSS, you need to set up a route for it and generate the css from a PHP-file, like any other page, but with the content type you already have.

Comment: Can you please explain me more ?@Magnus Eriksson

Comment: create a css .teacher .student etc class, in your view file add class depending on session

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things to access session from outside models,views and controllers..

1.Create the CI instance first...

```
$CI = &get instance();
```

2.Then load session library ..

```
$CI->load->library('session');
```

3.Now access session's variable as

```
$type = $CI->session->userdata('type');
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function in your controller that return the user type and then you call it in your css file using curl, it will work.
Controler:

```
public function user_type() { 
  $userType = $this->session->get_userdata('usertype'); echo $userType; 
}
```

CSS:

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'localhost/test/user/user_type'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$type = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); 

if($type == "admin") { 
  $settingButtonColor = "#990000"; 
} 

if($type == "student") { 
   $settingButtonColor = "#990001"; 
} 

if($type=="teacher") { 
  $settingButtonColor = "#990002"; 
} 
?>

.sett_btn { 
  background-color:<?php echo $settingButtonColor;?> !important; 
}
```

Comment: Please put the code in your answer and not in images

Comment: In answer not in comment

Answer (score 0):

```
Function 

public function user_type()
 {
        $userType = $this->session->get_userdata('usertype');

        echo $userType;
    }

CSS

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/test/user/user_type');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $type = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

    if($type=="admin")
         {
 $settingButtonColor = "#990000";
    }
```